# How can I know when the split-window drag handle is present on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout

When an app is running in a third of an iPad screen, there is a small drag handle at the top of its window. In iOS 10, dragging on that handle lets you switch what app is open there. In iOS 11, you can use it to change the app from taking up a third of the screen to floating over the rest of the screen.

[image: example of overlapping elents]

My question: how do I know when this handle is present, or at least know that there's something taking up that space? I need to lay out my UI content around it without [conflicting with it](https://twitter.com/CodingItWrong/status/911951405564522496). It [doesn't appear to work with iOS 11's Safe Area APIs](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6159836374892544).

[See here](https://github.com/tomhamming/rdar_35785520) for a sample project trying to put a label at the top of a window without overlaying the drag handle. Run it in a third of an iPad screen.

Answer (score 1):

Start by duplicating the radar. This is definitely something that should be handled by the safe area magic.

The issue here is that the handle is rendered by SpringBoard, so you can only apply tricks to guess whether it is currently visible. You can determine whether the window is at the right size and whether it is at the correct location on screen, and then add some extra safe area insets. This is normally ill-advised for several reasons, such as not knowing all cases where the handle appears, having to take into account left-to-right systems, etc., but in this case, the problem seems so egregious, I'm not sure I'd recommend leaving as is.

**Edit**

One more option is to see if `UIWindow.safeAreaInsets` returns a correct value. `UINavigationController` is able to deduce the safe area correctly, so it is hiding there somewhere.

Comment: The radar I linked to is mine, and it's marked as a dupe already. `UIWindow`'s safe area insets appear to always be all zeroes, so no luck there. But I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but you don’t use a `UINavigationController`, right? If you wrap your controller in one, does it help?

Comment: No, I don't use a navigation controller, and I do enough custom stuff with that title bar that I really can't use one.

Comment: You do know you can use a custom bar with the controller, right?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want a subclass of `UINavigationBar`. I have my own custom bar there with all its own behaviors and custom subviews and such.